# How to share the current webview link?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, share

I have my WebViewFragment what extends Fragment.

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {
```

The Websites are opened with a String Array.

```
    int position = getArguments().getInt("position");

    String url = getArguments().getString("url");

    String[] menus = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Websites);
```

I would like to share the current webview let´s say i´m on stackoverflow.com and i click on share i want to share this link.
If i click on questions i want to share that link long story short i want to share always the current webview.

I can´t find anything what´s working with fragment...

If you need some code or more information let me know!

Thx for your help dudes

EDIT:

I made it nearly working with:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_share, menu);
    MenuItem shareItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);
    ShareActionProvider mShare = (ShareActionProvider) shareItem.getActionProvider();
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, webView.getUrl());

    mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    return;
}

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // handle item selection
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.menu_share:
             // do s.th.
             return true;
          default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

       }

 }
```

and in `public View onCreateView`
i put `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

but i can only share the base url with that what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use webviewClient and override the following method:

```
 @Override  
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
   view.loadUrl(url);  
//share this url
   return true;  
}
```

Comment: no i mean i want to know if i can use share action provider with fragment?